# Can a WCF service configured to be consumable by different protocol?

Tags: wcf, protocols

I am reading through the WCF 4.0 Cookbook, I am impressed by the unification protocol capability of WCF, and I just come up with this question:

Is a hosted service using 1 protocol like HTTP\named pipe? or a hosted service can be consumed by different protocol client like HTTP, named pipe at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

If you setup the service with Multiple Bindings then yes it can listen and respond on different transport protocols.

Obviously if you initiate communication on http then you will get a response back over the same transport.

This msdn link provides details on when you would choose the different transports.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx

Comment: Thanks, very quick response. it is a convenient feature.

Comment: Yes it can make life alot easier especially if you need to provide backward compatibility when replacing older services but also provide newer clients with a more secure or different way to connect.